# Is there a way I can track sequences in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sequence

The dataframe contains all team possessions that end in a goal. Each row represents a ball event detailing what player was involved the type of action and the pos x and pos y it occurred on the pitch.

```
#sample df
pass_goal = pd.DataFrame({'match_id': [1107073,1107073,1107073,1409630,1409630,1409630,1509730,1509730,1509730,1509730], 
'possession_number': [2,2,2,40,40,40,100,100,100,100], 
'second': [10,15,20,250,260,270,300,310,320,330], 
'action_name': ['pass', 'pass', 'goal','pass','pass','goal','pass','pass','pass','goal'], 
'player_name': ['a','b','b','b','a','a','d','e','c','c',]})
```

So my issue is that I want track the different sequences/flows that occur for each possession. One approach I tried but failed with was counting unique players by the possession_id.

For e.g. possession 2 => player a passes to player b, player b shoots and scores (I want to define this as ABG), another example could be possession 40 => player b passes to player a, player a shoots and scores (even though the players names are different this should also be defined as the same sequence as the first one)

Obviously there are a lot more complicated combinations like ABCDAG multiple players involved but I kept the sample df as simple as possible

Not sure there is such an easy approach to this but my preferred output if achievable would be

```
Sequence        Count
ABG               2
ABCG              1
```

Comment: In other words, you don't care for order or the number of occurrences of players in a possession?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different problems here:

1. concatenate the players from a single possession into a unique string
2. tranform those string so that they are independant of the players names

First problem can be solved with a groupby:

```
val = pd.Series(pass_goal['player_name'])
val[pass_goal['action_name'] == 'goal'] = 'G'
tmp = val.groupby(pass_goal['possession_number']).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.tolist()))
```

It gives:

```
possession_number
2       abG
40      baG
100    decG
Name: player_name, dtype: object
```

If would then use a specific function to transform those strings:

```
def trans(s):
    resul = []
    d = {}
    for i in s:
        if i == 'G':
            resul.append(i)
        else:
            if i not in d:
                d[i] = chr(ord('A') + len(d))
            resul.append(d[i])
    return ''.join(resul)
```

Demo:

```
>>> trans('abG')
'ABG'
>>> trans('baG')
'ABG'
```

Ok, let's apply trans and count:

```
tmp = tmp.apply(trans)
resul = tmp.groupby(tmp).count().rename('count').reset_index().rename(
         columns={'player_name': 'sequence'})
```

It gives as expected:

```
  sequence  count
0     ABCG      1
1      ABG      2
```

Comment: thanks for this, one other issue if the possesion_id is not unique on its own and I needed to group by the match_id also, can I just add the match_id column where tmp is declared?